# How to hide cookie notice when embedding a PandaDoc document

Tags: iframe, pandadoc

I'm using a sandbox credentials and testing embedding a PandaDoc document in an iframe. When the document loads the cookie notice is displayed every time. Is it possible to hide this notice?

[image: document loading with cookie notice]

https://developers.pandadoc.com/reference/embed-a-document

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed recently in PandaDoc, and this popup is no longer showing up. Please let us know, if you're still experiencing this issue: intregrations@pandadoc.com